# Is this matrix always semi-definite?

Tags: matrices, vectors, positive-definite

Assume I have a 3D vector $v$ and $\times$ is a dyadic product.

Is matrix

$$
M = v \times v' 
$$

always positive semi-definite?

Computing $x^T M x$ gives us $(x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + x_3 v_3)^2$, which is always positive or zero. Have i missed anything in the proof?

Comment: As you think, $M$ is always semi definite and positive definite iff $v\neq 0$. This matrix is rank 1 and the unique nonzero eigenvalue is $\| v \|^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give me the hint why the eigenvalue is the trace of the matrix?

Comment: In this case, there is only one (possibly) non-zero eigenvalue, so
trace = sum of eigenvalues = non-zero eigenvalue.

Comment: To see the eigenvalues more clearly, choose an orthogonal basis $\{v, u_1, u_2,\dots, u_{n-1}\}$ and compute the action of $M$ on each basis vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $M=vv^{\intercal}$ is always semi-positive definite.

$\forall  x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $x^{\intercal}Mx=x^{\intercal}vv^{\intercal}x = x^{\intercal}v(x^{\intercal}v)^{\intercal} = (x^{\intercal}v)^2 \ge 0$.
Note that $x^{\intercal}v$ is a scalar, thus $x^{\intercal}v=(x^{\intercal}v)^{\intercal}$.

However, $M$ may not be positive definite when $v \ne \mathbf{0}$ and $n > 1$: $x^{\intercal}Mx = 0 \Leftrightarrow v^{\intercal}x = 0$, where there is non-zero solution for $x$.